# DLL causes Winforms UI to run slow in certain scenarios

Tags: c#, dll, user-interface

I have a `VideoObject` class which makes use of a C++ DLL to capture images and video from a webcam.  I've been told the DLL makes use of DirectShow to do this.  It also seems to start a couple of its own threads which I have no control over.

The `VideoObject` class seems to work fine in itself; I can capture images and video.  However, its use negatively affects the performance of the main UI: it gets very laggy.

If I instantiate my `VideoObject` like this

```
public partial class ParentForm : Form

    private VideoObject videoObject;

    public ParentForm()
    {
        videoObject = new VideoObject();
    }
}
```

then the UI becomes very laggy.  My guess is that whatever the `VideoObject`'s underlying DLL is doing, it's affecting my application's UI thread.

Now, I can mitigate this lagginess by starting the `VideoObject` instance in an MTA thread of its own.  (I'm completely new to C#, so I'm guessing the following may not be very clever.)

```
public partial class ParentForm : Form

    private VideoObject videoObject;
    private Thread videoObjectThread;

    public ParentForm()
    {
        videoObjectThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => videoObject = new VideoObject()));
        videoObjectThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
        videoObjectThread.Start();
    }
}
```

I can now interact with the `videoObject` instance and the UI does not lag, but only if I make no further reference to the instance in the Form's constructor.

If I in any way interact with this threaded instance in the Form's constructor, the UI will become laggy again.  It's as though any direct interaction with an instance of `VideoObject` in my Form's constructor will induce the laggy behaviour of the UI.

Does anybody have any insights into the behaviour I'm seeing?

**Edit**:  I should probably clarify what I mean by 'laggy'.  I mean that the main panel's UI becomes perpetually laggy and slow.  Nothing else is affected; all operations on the VideoObject work as expected and do not run slower or delayed in any way.

If I don't 'touch' the VideoObject in the Form's constructor, the UI works perfectly.  Subsequently calling the VideoObject's methods doesn't cause the UI to run slow either.

It all seems to hinge on whether or not I access the VideoObject in the main Form's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call into a method on the Video object it must have some overhead that temporarily blocks the thread you are using to interact with the video object. Maybe the Video component has to load large object into memory when methods are called or object is instantiated.

Have you tried making asynchronous calls to the methods on the video object? Effectively not blocking while waiting for the video object to return from whatever it's doing.

Without knowing the specifics of the video component its hard to make a guess.

One thing you could think about is maybe wrapping the video object in a WCF service and hosting it in it's own process and then using NetTcpBinding to interact with the component.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  There is some initial overhead as the object initialises, but little else.  Even when I'm not interacting with the instance, the UI is still very laggy.  Something 'under-the-hood' in the DLL is causing the problem I think.  I've made an edit to try to better explain the symptoms. Cheers again.

Comment: Yes, the video component essentially exposes the DLL's functionality.  I don't have the DLL's code though; all I've been told is it uses DirectShow!